# How to nest if and or not Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm struggling with the following:

I have price ranges from

- 100 - 200
- 201 - 300
- 301 - 400
- 401 - 500
- 501 - 600

In every range I give a number from 1-5. I'm trying to give a a number from 1 to 5 to a cell that will check in which price range is.

For example if I write in price field `150` it has to give me to the cell with the formula the number `1` according to the ranges I have. So far I've tried the following but I cannot nest more than 3 `if`s.

```
=IF(AND(B9>=A10,B9<=C10),"1",(IF(AND(B9>=A11,B9<=C11),"2",IF(B9>=A12,B9<=C12,"3"))))
```

Comment: If your price ranges are uniformly staggered as per your example, use `=INT(B9/100)`.

Comment: apparantly they are not.. Im looking something that will work with every numeric figure i give...  i guess i was pretty clear. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 2):

You could use `=SUMPRODUCT()` to do this. There are also some CSE formulas that would do the trick, but I prefer non-CSE since those can be finicky if someone messes with the formula and doesn't enter them properly:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B9>=$A$10:$A$19)*(B9<=B10:B19)*(ROW($A$10:$A$19)-9))
```

`Sumproduct` will test each condition here that is then being multiplied together. The conditions in this formula are: `(B9>=$A$10:$A$19)` and `(B9<=B10:B19)` which are pretty self explanatory. From each condition, for each row in the range it gets a `1` or `0` (TRUE or FALSE) and then multiplies that by the `ROW()-9` for each row being tested. In the end you get the `ROW()-9` for whichever row has two TRUE conditions, or `1 * 1 * (Row()-9)`.

Note that because it tests each row, only one row should return two true conditions, otherwise you'll add up row numbers and get bad results.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a cross-reference table of the minimum amounts for each price range in ascending order. From your sample data this could be Z2:Z7.

[image]

Your formula to examine the value entered into B9 would be,

```
=IFERROR(IF(B9<MAX($Z$2:$Z$7), MATCH(B9, $Z$2:$Z$7), NA()), "not in range")
```

If everything equal-to-and-above 501 should be in price group *5* then simply remove the top values (e.g. *601*) and the check for the maximum.

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(B9, $Z$2:$Z$6), "not in range")
```

That will still return *not in range* for values less than *100* but anything over *500* will return price group *5*.

Comment: the only thing is that if this number goes above 601 it doesnt give me the top value it returns not it range.. How i can make it to give the final value in everything above 601?

Comment: It's unclear on whether the top values should a *5* for everything above *501* or if a new *6* value should be available for everything above *601*.